# Is there any way of finding the font & frame size of the UINavigationBar title?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Is there any way of programatically returning the font and size of the navigation controller's title bar (e.g. `self.title.frame.size` or `self.title.font`, although I know neither of those works)?

*(In case you're wondering the reason, I would like to use an NSString `sizeWithFont` method to work out how much text can fit in the title before I truncate it. I could do this by physically measuring the font and frame size myself (e.g. I think it's Helvetica 15), but I want the actual title to report its own font and size, to make my app future-proof.)*

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 5.0, UINavigationBar has a property called titleTextAttributes. This is a dictionary containing attributes described by the [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893).

If I print out this dictionary in one of my projects, I get the following:

```
Font = "<UICFFont: 0x998e690> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 20px";
TextColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.2 1";
TextShadowColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0";
TextShadowOffset = "UIOffset: {0, 0}";
```

...which shows the bold default system font at 20px. You can also change these as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out how to get the frame:

`self.navigationItem.titleView.frame.size`

Which just leaves the font. My research indicates that it's the System Font at size 20, but I'd love it to be self-reporting.

EDIT - well that's odd. If I do ...

```
 self.title = @"test";
 NSLog(@"Width is: %f", self.navigationItem.titleView.frame.size.width);
```

... I get random negative numbers from the NSLog. So it doesn't look like the title frame is right.

Comment: FYI: The font is the system font, which will *either* be Helvetica *or* Helvetica-Neue (Apple switched the system font when iOS 4 came along).

Comment: titleView is a UIView, which has a font property.

Comment: @Lou if I try `self.navigationItem.titleView.font`, I get *Property 'font' not found on object of type 'UIView'*.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be a UILabel -- UINavBarPrompt doesn't expose the font -- it looks like it's hardcoded into the implementation.  @lxt says it's System font -- you could look that up.

Comment: @Lou thanks - I'll have to hard-code it. I was just hoping that I could get it to return its own font, in case Apple makes changes in future.

Comment: titleView is not set by default. It is used to customize the navigationItem if you do not want to use the default title. From the docs: "If this property value is nil, the navigation item’s title is displayed in the center of the navigation bar when the receiver is the top item. If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title."